# Angular 4 POST to php my sql not working

Tags: php, mysql, sql, angular

I Am trying to make a simple login check , using angular 4 , php my sql .
Now i am able to send the details to the php , but i am not able to receive the status after it , i have no idea why.

Simply, i want to check if the username and password are correct, then return some json , else , return false result.

Help please.

Angular :

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';  
import { Http,  Response ,RequestOptions,Headers} from '@angular/http';
import { Observable } from 'rxjs/Observable';
import 'rxjs/add/operator/map'

@Injectable()
export class appService {  

    postResponse:any ;
    status;
    constructor(private http:Http) { }

   insertData() {
    let headers = new Headers({ 'Content-Type': 'application/json' });
    let options = new RequestOptions({ headers: headers });
    return this.http.post('http://localhost:80/angularsql/sql.php',JSON.stringify({firstName:'Joe',lastName:'Smith333'}),{headers:headers})
    .map((res: Response) => res.json())
    .subscribe((res:'') => this.postResponse = res);
   }
}
```

PHP

```
<?php 
header("Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *");
header("Access-Control-Allow-Methods: PUT, GET, POST");
header("Access-Control-Allow-Headers: Origin, X-Requested-With, Content-Type, Accept");
$data = json_decode( file_get_contents('php://input'),true );
  $fname =  $data['firstName'];
  $lname =  $data['lastName'];

$con = new mysqli('localhost','root','','angular');
if($fname=='anan' && $lname=='kassis') {
$sql = "insert into users_tbl(firstName,lastName) values('".$fname."','".$lname."')";
$result = $con->query($sql);
    $data = [ "status" => "CORRECT" ];
echo json_encode($data);
}
else {
    $data = [ "status" => "wrong details inserted" ];
echo json_encode($data);
}
//echo $result;
```

?>

Comment: I Know that i insert into , is not to check and select and so on :)
my mistake i didn't clarify  this before..
the whole idea, is to get back the json to angular. 
 this is what i am not able to achieve .

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you should change

```
subscribe((res:'') => this.postResponse = res);
```

to

```
 subscribe(res: any => 
{
    this.postResponse = res);
    console.log(res.status)
}
```

Here, res will be an object and you can console.log(res.status)

**Edit**: You cannot have the console.log after the subscribe call, because at this stage the http call has not received a response yet.

**Other things to consider:**

And probably set json type headers in your php response

```
header('Content-Type: application/json');
```

Also, you should use parametrized queries (like PDO) when querying your database

Comment: i did 
.subscribe((res:any) => this.postResponse = res),
    console.log(this.postResponse);
i get in the response, undefined. but i tried running the script again , and it gave me the result..
so looks like , i am getting the console.log , faster than the response 
u have any idea how can i solve this ?

Comment: I edited my answer. Make sure the console log is in the subscribe method

Comment: This worked !!!!!!!!
The question is , 

.subscribe( data => {
    this.status = data,
    console.log(this.status);
    });
after it , when i do console.log outside the subscribe function , i get undefined ! and i am not able to understand why .. but if i put the {{status}} in my component.html , then it shows object object, that is ok for now why it is object object, i will handle it .. but do you have any idea, why i can't console.log it outside the subscription method ???

Comment: Angular hasn't received the response from the server yet at this stage. Subscribe is kinda like a callback triggered when the response has arrived. And if you want to display status, do either this.status = data.status, or {{status.status}} in your html (one or the other)

Comment: You are a king man :)
You helped me, solve a huge problem in my life that i have been stuch with , for a lot of time :)

Comment: Welcome. Please accept the answer if it helped resolve your issue

Comment: Will you please, let me know, how can i now , change this object that i have , to an array ?

Comment: You'd have to elaborate more than that. Please Open another question maybe

Comment: Click in the tick on the left of the answer

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48875782/angular-4-post-to-php-my-sql-not-working-please

Answer (score 0):

I think this line is the issue:

```
.subscribe((res:'') => this.postResponse = res);
```

Change your call into:

```
 insertData(): Observable<any> {
    let headers = new Headers({ 'Content-Type': 'application/json' });
    let options = new RequestOptions({ headers: headers });
    return this.http.post('http://localhost:80/angularsql/sql.php', JSON.stringify({
      firstName: 'Joe',
      lastName: 'Smith333'
    }), { headers: headers })
      .map(res => res.json())
      .catch((error: any) => Observable.throw(
        { message: error.json().message, details: error.json().details }));
  }
```

You should subscribe to the `insertData()` method. And in your `.post()` you map the result and you catch the errrors (if any).

Comment: Let me try and see what happens.

Comment: Theoritically it should work .. i guess .. because , what i am facing actually, is getting undefined, and if i run the same function insertdata again , i receive the json .. so looks, that i subscribe to it ,faster than i receive the data from the php .. so i am going to try and let you know.

Comment: insertData() {
    let headers = new Headers({ 'Content-Type': 'application/json' });
    let options = new RequestOptions({ headers: headers });
    return this.http.post('http://localhost:80/angularsql/sql.php',JSON.stringify({firstName:'Joe',lastName:'Smith333'}),{headers:headers})
    .map((res: Response) => res.json());
   }

myInsert() {
    this._appService.insertData()
    .subscribe( data => this.status = data);
    console.log(this.status);
}

Comment: @AnanKassis Can you edit your answer adding the error output? Or your updated code?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48875782/angular-4-post-to-php-my-sql-not-working-please

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48875782/angular-4-post-to-php-my-sql-not-working-please